# Build statistical model

Tags: regression, modeling

I need to build model where y depends on x (y~x). But while I have the usual data for Y, I only have a range of values for X, e.g.

```
X=4..5; Y=2
X=4..5; Y=2.1
X=5..7; Y=3
....
X=10..12; Y=8
```

I think standard regression and OLS can not be used. What a way to build the model?

The Y value actually represents an average of several values​​, the corresponding values ​​of X are unknown, known only to the range.

Comment: Is the range always the same? Then taking the averages could be a solution.

Comment: It does not violate the Gauss-Markov conditions?

Comment: Why should it? GM is about the error term, you should do model checking in either case.

Comment: In this case, X have a random error, I think this should never be.

Comment: As I said, as long as there is no special situation, in which the range increases or decreases, or depends on the Y it should not.

Comment: The solution surely depends on why you have interval data for the covariates.

Comment: @StatTistician I do not know how X distributed within the range. Real average X may not equal the middle of range.

Comment: @Stéphane What kinds of solutions can be?

Comment: @Andy I don't know. May be googling with the keyword "interval censored covariates" could give some hints.

Comment: @Andy regression with random errors in x's can be done so 'should never be' is too strong. You just shouldn't do it with OLS. That said, I agree with Stéphane Laurent that these are interval-censored covariates